# Trying to access array offset on value of type null in Laravel cart

Tags: php, laravel

when i click shopping cart button it show error 'Trying to access array offset on value of type null in Laravel'.

```php
Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::handleError
C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-ecommerce\app\Listeners\CartUpdatedListener.php:30
```

```php
public function handle($event)
    {
        $couponName = session()->get('coupon')['name'];
        if ($couponName) {
            $coupon = Coupon::where('code', $couponName)->first();
            dispatch_now(new UpdateCoupon($coupon));
        }
    }
```

Please kindly help. Thank in advance

Comment: You need to provide more information for your question. line of error code... At first glance it looks like your `session()->get('coupon')` is returning `null` . so can't access key `name`

Comment: I think the data that you are trying to fetch from your db is not available

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public function handle($event)
{
    $session_coupon = session()->get('coupon');

    if($session_coupon && isset($session_coupon['name'])){
        $coupon = Coupon::where('code', $session_coupon['name'])->first();
        dispatch_now(new UpdateCoupon($coupon));
    } else {
        dd("if $session_coupon is null or $session_coupon has doesn't exist 'name' key");
    }
}
```

Comment: i try that script. it still showing the same error @Natvarsinh Parmar - bapu

Comment: `dd($session_coupon);` and check the session data what will print. @ZinMyoSwe

Answer (score 0):

It is occur because my session coupon doesn't exists. so, i add null validation in script. Error was solved

**Fix ecommerce Listeners\CartUpdatedListener error**

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/fix-ecommerce-listenerscartupdatedlistener-error

```php
public function handle($event)
    {
        $couponName = session()->get('coupon')['name']??null;

        if ($couponName) {
            $coupon = Coupon::where('code', $couponName)->first();

            dispatch_now(new UpdateCoupon($coupon));
        }
    }
```